# fatal: corrupt patch at line 7

Tags: git

Как применить данный [патч](https://github.com/google/zopfli/issues/93)?
я загрузил проект [zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli), сохранил патч в файл и запускаю:

```
cd C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\zopfli
git apply C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\new.patch
```

Мне выдает:

> fatal: corrupt patch at line 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я смог воспроизвести такую ошибку, преобразовав окончания строк в файле с патчем к [принятому в *ms/windows* виду `crlf`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.92_ASCII).

этой ошибки не возникает, если преобразовать окончания строк к виду `lf` с помощью, например, программы `dos2unix`. как пишут [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27814403/4827341) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852277/4827341), эта программа должна быть доступна и в *ms/windows* (в результате установки *git*). в других ответах к упомянутым вопросам приводят также иные советы по преобразованию `crlf→lf` (например, с помощью *notepad+*).

впрочем, этот патч всё равно придётся накладывать вручную (если это вообще имеет смысл), так как он не соответствует исходным текстам:

```
$ git apply new.patch
error: patch failed: src/zopfli/deflate.c:396
error: src/zopfli/deflate.c: patch does not apply
```

---

для справки: неплохое описание т.н. [универсального формата, используемого программой diff](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#.D0.A3.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.81.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82), в котором и сохранён приведённый патч. кстати, это далеко не единственный формат патчей, поддерживаемый программой *diff*. некоторые (по-моему, не все) приведены в той же самой статье из википедии.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Вы не могли бы подсказать, как тогда применить данный патч в ручную?

Comment: @lorents, на беглый взгляд применение этого патча вряд ли имеет какой-то смысл — он совсем не соответствует текущему содержимому исправляемого файла. я думаю, за уточнениями лучше обратиться к тому, кто опубликовал этот патч. // но если хотите попробовать вручную применить патч, то в википедии есть неплохое описание т.н. [универсального формата, используемого программой diff](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#.D0.A3.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.81.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82) (приведённый патч — именно в этом формате).