# Перезаписывается весь файл при commit-е

Tags: linux, git

Как в Ubuntu файлы мержить, а не заменять?

Проблема такова: сделал какие-либо изменения в файле, и хочу его слить с таким же файлом в проекте, но если просто копирую в папку, то получается так, что предыдущая версия удаляется, а настоящая записывается и когда я делаю `commit`, то *git* у меня записывает, что сначала удалили N строк, а потом добавили N строк. Из-за этого очень некрасиво выглядит `patch`.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: переводы строк поправьте. см. [1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.92_ASCII), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497894/178576) и [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474751/178576)

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич, попробуйте ``vimdiff``, ``Kdiff3``, для пользователей Windows - ``WinMerge``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

проблема, судя по всему, заключается в том, что при изменении файла вы подменяете и [символы перевода строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.92_ASCII).

узнать, какие именно символы используются в файле для обозначения перевода строк можно, например, с помощью программы *file*:

```
$ file *
dos.lines:   ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
macos.lines: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
unix.lines:  ASCII text
```

преобразовать эти символы можно, например, программами из пакета *dos2unix* — `dos2unix`, `unix2dos`, `mac2unix` и `unix2mac`.

пример:

```
$ file dos.lines
dos.lines: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ dos2unix dos.lines
dos2unix: converting file dos.lines to Unix format...
$ file dos.lines
dos.lines: ASCII text
```

---

доп. чтение: [Как настроить autocrlf в git для различных систем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/406466/178576)