# Atom IDE произвольное изменение строк

Tags: git, плагин, atom

Пользуюсь **Atom IDE**, установлены плагины для **GIT'а**, использую тему **Material theme** (может быть кому то это что то даст), в общем проблема такая, что в **php** файлах при **сохранении** файла, даже если я изменил всего один символ, он добавляет изменения очень странные,берет 2-3 строки (хз как выбирает) и удаляет их, а потом вставялет их же, без каких то либо изменений.
При этом **GIT** фиксирует это изменение... 
Вот скрин в blob формате: "blob:https://web.telegram.org/04094604-204d-47b0-a083-f8cd090bdfa0"

Comment: и как смотреть этот скрин? да, я понимаю, что пара человек использует телеграм, но основная масса нет.

Comment: хоть и пользуюсь телегой, не могу скрин посмотреть. Кинь сюда дифф того, что у тебя в стейдже

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/772869/178576

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Перед ссылкой есть слово "blob:", если его вписать перед моей ссылкой, то увидите изображение)))

Comment: Вот тот [скрин](https://pastenow.ru/64bb540124a13339b889f80c570f0ce7)

Comment: А по поводу проблемы перезаписи коммита, там я так понял перезапись происходит при самом коммите, а у меня при простом сохранении файла...

Comment: Аа, все понял, про что там) сейчас попробуем)

Comment: Странно, но не помогло..
Вот мои конфиги гита:

[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true

Comment: думаю, что вся проблема в  том, что атом решил исправлять переводы строк. Видимо в тех местах они отличаются от линуксовых. Этот проект делался с других осей (винды/мака)?

Comment: Нет, остальные работают на Linux в NetBeans :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что все IDE испльзуют свой символ перехода на следующую строку, если в команде разработчики используют разные IDE, у которых разный перенос строки, то при сохранении файла чужие переносы строк будут заменяться на свои :)