# Изменения в одинаковых строках при слиянии git

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

Почему весь коммит с одной стороны выделяется, как разный в сравнении с другим, хотя строчки почти все одинаковые  (использую гиткракен, но дело не в нём, пробовал в консоли делать, то же самое)  ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ¿Может окончания строк различаются?

Comment: @user7860670, что, простите?

Comment: Ну типа `\n` или `\r\n`.

Comment: @user7860670, нет, там всё одинаковое, создал два файла даже новых, проверил, всё равно странно отображается

Comment: попробуйте любой другой программой для diff, хоть с консоли.

Comment: @KoVadim, вы читали вопрос? Я же написал, что в консоли пробовал тоже

Comment: перечитал. Но консоль видели только Вы. Но я соглашусь с @user7860670 - там скорее всего переводы строк.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса // в данном случае лучше было приложить вывод программы *git*.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перезаписывается весь файл при commit-е](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772869/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-commit-%d0%b5)

Comment: Файловые системы одинаковые для хранения?

Comment: @0andriy, да, конечно

Comment: Если проводите эксперимент на файлах в 10+ строчек, то же самое? Например, первые пять-шесть строчек файла остаются нетронутыми (по-вашему мнению), что показывает тогда утилита сравнения?

Comment: @0andriy, я сливал огромные файлы в 100+ строк, то же самое, всё разное...может, это баг из-за первого коммита

Comment: Ну так вы шестнадцатиричный дамп смотрели? Переводы строк соответствуют?

Comment: @0andriy, да, + вбивал на разных сайтах, где текст сравнивается...самое характерное, что, например, в CLion всё в порядке, он правильно видит, какие строки здесь разные